# angularjs $resource.query with complex structure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

all my rest API for the query (e.g. `/clubs`) return an object that is of this form:

```
{
"total": 10,
"results": [...]
}
```

the `$resourece.query` expect an array.

what's the correct way to parse this response?

- Should I override in the definition of the resource the query setting `isArray: false`? (if I set the functions to override the `query` do I've to re-set all the other methods such as `get` `save` etc?)
- Should I create a parseFunction to parse the result and return an array? if so, how?
- how can I create a my resource in a way that I don't have to replicate the code for every resource? basically extending the current `$resource` object to override the configuration, or the parsing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you receiving back is an object and not an array, so use `$resource.get`, then you can access the results array from the object

Comment: But with the get I should get a single club. And I've the resource url set as /clubs/:Id . And actually I would like to have two different calls instead of ha in a single get functions for two porpouses.

Comment: If you can change what the API is returning, then you should change it to be just an array and not an array wrapped in an object. If you can't change what the API is returning to you, then you'll have to either add a new method to handle querying or override `$resource.query`. It's more work that way.

Comment: But isn't there anyway to extend the `$resource` class creating a `myResource` class that does not expect an array? how can I extend a angualr module/class? anyway it works with `get()` it just i don't like much the idea to use `get` to get all the result and also the datails.

Comment: To extend $resource, you would just create another service that wraps $resource and adds whatever additional methods you want. At that point it's really just creating extra work for yourself though as you'll likely end up just calling `$resource.get` under the hood of that service to access the collections you're returning. Angular is a very opinionated framework and the way the collection is wrapped goes against what Angular wants you to do.

Comment: I see, i'll go for your solution. In your last line " Angular is a very opinionated framework and the way the collection is wrapped goes against what Angular wants you to do." you  mean in the case I will wrap the collection as I had in mind or generally speaking?

Comment: Wrapping the collection. By wrapping the collection of clubs in an object you no longer have a collection of Club objects, you now have a ClubCollection object, which is a different resource than a Club.